# Replacing container view of UIActionSheet with my custom view

Tags: uiview, containers, uiactionsheet

I am developing an iPhone application in which I want to customize the action sheet with my own background image for action sheet and buttons.
I can write my own view which behaves like UIActionSheet. But, UIActionSheet by itself has some standard behavior like blocking orientation events. We might not be aware of such things. So, for safety purpose, it is better to have UIActionSheet itself; by replacing all its views with my custom view.

For this I have done the following things:
1. Create UIActionSheet. Call showOnView: on that action sheet.
2. Set the delegate as myController
3. In the delegate method willPresentActionSheet: remove all the subviews and add my custom view as action-sheet's sub-view

The problem is that I cannot get the animation affect of Action Sheet with my custom view, Because,UIActionSheet is animated before calling willPresentActionSheet (in showInView). If I override showInView and add my own animation I might miss the behavior like:
1. Blocking orientation events
2. Some of the views (the argument of showInView:) might no support orientation. I should be able to apply same orientation to my action-sheet in showInView.

Could someone help me out in achieving customization?

Thanks and Regards, Deepa